# Flutter querying different levels of data in Streambuilder

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to access two levels of information in Firebase. The top level collection is called messages and the second level is called chats. I am having trouble accessing the data snapshot retrieved of the Chats collection. Here is a screen print of my collections:

[image]

And here please find the code:

```
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: _firestore
      .collection('messages')
      .where("senderId", isEqualTo: currentUserId)
      .where("receiverId", isEqualTo: member.id)
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
      );
    }
    final messageHeaders = snapshot.data!.docs.reversed;
    print("messages first = ${messageHeaders.first.id}");
    List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
    for (var messageHeader in messageHeaders) {
      print(messageHeader["senderId"]);
      
      for (var messageDetail in messageHeader["chats"]) {
        print(messageDetail["text"]);
      }
```

So in the print statements above. The one to print the "senderId" is working fine. But not the one to print the "text"

Any help with this would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore queries are **shallow**, meaning that you don't get the entire subtree when you query a document. In your case, `chats` is a subcollection, therefore it will not be queried with the document.

So after getting the document snapshot, **you have to make another Firestore query** to get `chats` subcollection for that specific document in `messages` collection.